# Makefile recognizes only changed prerequisites, not new ones

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

Trying to write a simple makefile to compile Markdown files to HTML with Pandoc. I don't want to have to add all the prerequisite `.md` files explicitly to the makefile, so I've tried to use a pattern rule along with a wildcard prerequisite:

```
all: www/*.html

www/%.html: src/%.md
    pandoc -f markdown -t html $< > $@
```

This is close, but only processes prerequisite `.md` files for which an `.html` target file already exists and is out of date. New `.md` files which don't already have an `.html` file get ignored (so if all the non-new files are built, I get `make: Nothing to be done for 'all'.`)

What's the concept I'm missing? I'm not sure how to tell make to run on both the changed AND new `.md` files in `src/` and apply the pattern rule to each.

Comment: My hunch is `*.html` is being treated as anything that currently matches the pattern, not as a wildcard.  I'm not a Makefile expert by any stretch, but you'll probably want to look into variable substitution (something that's always eluded me).  Try this to start: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html

Comment: I think you're on the right track. If I clear out all the generated `*.html` files and run, it actually creates a file called `www/*.html` out of one of the prerequisites...definitely not treating the wildcard the way I expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could obtain a list of the `.html` files to be generated from the already existing `.md` files you have in the `src/` directory.

---

First, the list of the existing `.md` files can be obtained with the [`wildcard`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) built-in function:

```
md-files := $(wildcard src/*.md)
```

Then, apply a [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html) to the `md-files` variable, so that the `src/` prefix is removed and the suffix `.md` is replaced by `.html` for each element of the list of the `.md` files:

```
$(md-files:src/%.md=%.html)
```

Finally, by applying the [`addprefix`](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Name-Functions.html) built-in function to the resulting list, the prefix `www/` can be added to each element of that list:

```
html-files := $(addprefix www/,$(md-files:src/%.md=%.html))
```

Putting everything together, the resulting makefile would be:

```
md-files := $(wildcard src/*.md)
html-files := $(addprefix www/,$(md-files:src/%.md=%.html))

.PHONY: all
all: $(html-files)

www/%.html: src/%.md
    pandoc -f markdown -t html $< > $@
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$ cat Makefile
input := foo.md bar.md baz.md
output := $(input:%.md=www/%.html)

.PHONY: all

all: ${output}

www/%.html: src/%.md
        pandoc -f markdown -t html $< > $@

$ make -n
pandoc -f markdown -t html src/foo.md > www/foo.html
pandoc -f markdown -t html src/bar.md > www/bar.html
pandoc -f markdown -t html src/baz.md > www/baz.html
```